# Diferencias entre C++ y c++/cli

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un windows form, e indagando por la web, he visto que se trata del lenguaje c++/cli, pero no entiendo muy bien qué significa esto. Según tengo entendido, se trata de una modificación de c++ por parte de Windows, pero no le encuentro ningún tipo de relación con el lenguaje estándar, puesto que si quiero imprimir por consola en c++ usaría `std::cout << "Hola mundo"` y en c++/cli sería `Console::WriteLine("Hola Mundo");`

Por qué, si tiene una sintaxis tan distinta se considera parte del mismo lenguaje (una extensión o una modificacion)?

Comment: [CLI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_l%C3%ADnea_de_comandos) es interfaz de línea de comandos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es .Net. [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) es, en este caso, Common Lenguaje Interface

Comment: @eferion ah; de todas maneras es una pregunta *curiosa* es como preguntar las diferencias entre un micrófono y un megáfono cuando ambos sirven para ampliar tu voz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ es un lenguaje nativo (se genera un binario ejecutable).
C++.Net es un lenguaje basado en máquina virtual (forma parte de la familia .Net). En este caso el compilador no genera código ejecutable sino una suerte de código intermedio que es procesado por la máquina virtual de .Net durante la ejecución del programa. Esta máquina virtual es la encargada de convertir ese código intermedio en binario ejecutable.

La versión .Net de C++ no es un C++ puro sino que es una versión libre del lenguaje que se ha adaptado para ser compatible con la infraestructura .Net.

**Portabilidad:**

- El binario generado con C++ solo puede ser ejecutado en la máquina objetivo (el binario no es portable de windows a linux, por ejemplo)
- El código generado por C++.Net puede ser ejecutado sobre cualquier sistema que disponga de una instalación de .Net

**Ingeniería inversa:**

- El binario generador por C++ tiene una ingeniería inversa complicada ya que  la estructura de clases puede llegar a desaparecer por completo y la arquitectura del sistema queda reducida a un conjunto de funciones.
  El código generado por C++.Net puede ser decompilado con cierta facilidad, llegando a obtener los nombres de las funciones, las variables y la arquitectura del sistema. Al trabajar con .Net es normal pasar algun tipo de ofuscador que complique la ingenería inversa.

**Licencias:**

- Al trabajar con C++ tienes a tu disposición compiladores de código abierto muy buenos. También puedes optar por soluciones de pago
- C++.Net, al estar anclado a .Net, tiene pocas opciones de elección y casi todas pasan por usar el compilador de Microsoft o el que provee el proyecto MONO. Lo normal es que acabes supeditado a las licencias de Microsoft.

**Librería base:**

- La librería estándar de C++, si bien tiene características bastante potentes, es insuficiente de cara a realizar un proyecto serio. Con la entrada de los últimos estándares se ha hecho un gran esfuerzo para incorporar elementos básicos a dicha librería pero aun tiene muchas carencias.
- .Net pone a disposición del programador un extenso catálogo de librerías que permiten hacer auténticas maravillas (interfaz gráfica, criptografía, sockets, acceso a bases de datos, servicios de impresión, ...)

Y la cosa sigue...

Como ves las diferencias son notables y la elección de una u otra alternativa marcará completamente la forma de desarrollar tus proyectos.

Comment: Entonces, ¿donde puedo buscar información para aprender c++ .Net? Según tengo entendido, c++ es para programar en consola y .Net es para interfaz gráfica? P.D: por más que lo intento no entiendo c++.Net

Comment: @Jogofus .net es la infraestructura común para toda la familia .Net. siendo estrictos podrias programar tus aplicaciones en código intermedio directamente... c++ es, en este caso concreto, una extensión que permite generar el codigo intermedio a través de un pseudo-c++. La funcionalidad disponible con c++.net es la misma que con c# o vb.net, por poner un par de ejemplos